# Resolution vs. Dimensions when Supporting Multiple Resolutions

Tags: android, graphics

Android expects high, medium, and low density versions of all artwork in an Android application. According to the [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html), the artwork should be provided in 32x32 dp for various densities.

When working with raster graphics programs, there is no notion of dp. Are developers expected to use a constant pixel size between the versions and change the resolution, or use a constant resolution and change the dimensions? Or is this splitting hairs and it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a constant resolution and change the dimension. For ratio of dimension refer to how Launcher icon changes in size when we move from ldpi to xhdpi

```
ldpi  : 36 px
mdpi  : 48 px
hdpi  : 72 px
xhdpi : 96 px
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is your reasoning?

Comment: Constant pixel size will make your artifacts look smaller as screen density increases,